# Automatic update for Owncloud 9.1

Tags: upgrade, owncloud

I have a shared host server where I use the owncloud system to sync my data. I have upgraded to the newest version in the stable channel by a manual upgrade -> 9.1 
Today I saw on the website that there is a new version of owncloud (9.1.1.) since September 20 2016.

Is it normal behaviour that there is no auto update in the web ui (up to now) after a manual upgrade? Or is it normal that the release waits until it will be available through the web-ui update manager?

I dont want to upgrade my install by hand all the time - I hope it can be done the easy way again..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. The Owncloud updater never works reliable. I switched to Nextcloud which works a lot better. And it is fully open source and has more features.